# how do I write a set for g:select tag

Tags: grails, select

[image]How do I write options so I can generate it into an HTML select?  The problem with this is "options" needs a set, not an array

Here is everything I have.  I know the naming convention is bad, and I will fix that, but for right now I've been on this issue for days now.

Controller Class

```
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException
import grails.plugin.mail.*

class EmailServiceController {

    static defaultAction = "contactService"

def contactService() {
    def options = new ArrayList()
    options.push("Qestions about service")
    options.push("Feedback on performed service")
    options.push("Other")
    options.push("Why am I doing this")
    options
}

    def send() {
        sendMail(){
            to "mygroovytest@gmail.com"
            from params.email
            subject params.subject
            body params.information
        }
    }
}
```

Domain class

```
class EmailService {

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

g:select call from the gsp

```
<g:select name = "subject" from = "${options}" noSelection="Topic"/>
```

also tried the following with "${selectOptions}" instead of "${options}" with no luck

```
def selectOptions() {
    def options = new ArrayList()
    options.push("Qestions about service": "QAS")
    options.push("Feedback on performed service":"FoPS")
    options.push("Other":"Other")
    options.push("Why am I doing this":"WHY")
    return options
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need a `Set` instead of a `List`?

Comment: @doelleri stack trace : No signature of method: java.lang.String.entrySet() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: toSet(), toSet(), getBytes(), every()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I *think* I might know what is going on here.  The missing piece to the question is what gsp is being called.  Here is the appropriate way:

```
class EmailServiceController {

  def contactService() {
    def options = ["Qestions about service", "Feedback on performed service", "Other"]
    // assumes you are going to render contactService.gsp
    // you have to push the options to the view in the request
    [options:options]
  }

}
```

And then in contactService.gsp you would have:

```
<g:select name="subject" from="${options}" noSelection="['Topic': 'Topic']"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `options` is neither an array nor map. There is a syntax error. That's why you have only one option in your select. You need to enter either a real list or a map, like that:

```
def selectOptions() {
    def options = [:]
    options["Qestions about service"] = "QAS"
    options["Feedback on performed service"] = "FoPS"
    [options:options]
}
```

Using a map you can use it in the view like this:

```
<g:select name="subject" from="${options.entrySet()}" 
    optionValue="key" optionKey="value"
    noSelection="['Topic': 'Topic']"/>
```

Comment: Have you passed the options Array to the view?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes in your tags, not single quotes. With single quotes, you're just passing a String that looks like `'${options}'` instead of passing a GString with the value of `options`.

```
<g:select name="subject" from="${options}" noSelection="Topic"/>
```

In addition, assuming you're calling the `contactService` action, you need to `return options` instead of returning `options.push("Other")`. `push()` returns a boolean, which means the implicit return of `contactService` is the boolean result of `push()` instead of `options`.

Comment: what about the html  that says <option value="x">X</option> where you have a name, and a value?

Comment: What about HTML? We're not dealing with any straight HTML here.

Comment: see edited question.. Same result. Stacktrace : No signature of method: java.lang.String.entrySet() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: toSet(), toSet(), getBytes(), every()

Comment: I added a printscreen if it helps