# How to make a select box with constant list items with g:select

Tags: grails, groovy

I would like to make a select box using `<g:select/>` that translates to this html:

```
<select id="myselect" name="myselect">
  <option value="r">RED</option>
  <option value="g">GREEN</option>
  <option value="b">BLUE</option>
</select>
```

I would also like the value to be preselected from a bean when the page reloads.

I'm doing this inside a  so I have a table with each row having a separate option box.

I'm currently accomplishing this in the below html:

```
<g:each in=${mylist} status="i" var="myInst">
   <select id="status${myInst}" name="status${myInst}" data-id="${myInst.id}">
      <option value="r" <g:if test="${myInst.color == "r"}">selected</g:if>>RED</option>
      <option value="g" <g:if test="${myInst.color == "g"}">selected</g:if>>Green</option>
      <option value="b" <g:if test="${myInst.color == "b"}">selected</g:if>>BLUE</option>
   </select>
</g:each>
```

This all works fine but I'd like to change that ugly `<select>` into `<g:select>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<g:select id="myselect" name="myselect" value="${myInst.color}"
          from="${['r': 'RED', 'g': 'GREEN', 'b': 'BLUE']}"
          optionKey="key" optionValue="value" />
```

Comment: However, if you're going to do something like this, I suggest making a "selectColor" tag using a taglib.  Trying to find where you put all these magic constants when they're in GSPs is non-optimal.  Plus, it's much easier to test taglibs.

Answer (score -1):

you have to declare the "myselect" inside your domain class.  I have been having trouble with this too, but I'm about 2 weeks ahead of you.  see [how do I write a set for g:select tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864716/how-do-i-write-a-set-for-gselect-tag)

Comment: @Sharma his answer worked because his "from" is embedded inside the <g:select> statement. This is not the normal way of using the g:select.  As matter of fact, you get no benefit from using a g:select in this situation then if you were just to hardcode the select statement inside your GSP.  Normally speaking, you would use the g:select to retrieve your "from" items from a database or hard coded values inside your domain class (or application layer).  Not to mention it reduces the readability for people not used to grails

Comment: I'm confused why this keeps getting downvoted. Have people gotten that lazy that they just downvote without explaining anything